# Django: passing a URL parameter to every instance of a reverse URL lookup in a template tag

Tags: python, django

Sorry if the title is unclear, I'm not sure the best way to describe the issue. I have an application with a `Ticket` model and a `Team` model. All `Ticket`s are associated with a single `Team`. The issue I'm having is a problem of URL reversing. I'm trying to set it up my URLs like so: `/<team_pk>/tickets/` displays a list of tickets associated with the Team specified by `team_pk`. So `/1/tickets/` would display all of the tickets for the first Team. Both of these objects are in the app `tracker`.

To do this, I've set up my project/urls.py files like so:

**project/urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [ path('<team_pk>/', include('tracker.urls', namespace='tracker')), ]
```

**tracker/urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [ path('tickets/', views.TicketTable.as_view(), name='ticket_list'), ]
```

Then, inside my html templates, I have the following URL tag:

```html
href="{% url 'tracker:ticket_list' %}"
```

This results in a NoReverseMatch error:

```py
NoReverseMatch at /1/tickets/
Reverse for 'ticket_list' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<team_pk>[^/]+)/tickets/$']
```

What I would like is for the reverse match to just use the current value for the `team_pk` URL kwarg.

**What I have tried to fix it:**

I have found the following solution to the problem, but it involves a lot of repetition, and I feel like there must be a DRYer way.

First, I extend the `get_context_data()` method for every view on the site.

```py
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['current_team_pk'] = self.kwargs['team_pk']
    return context
```

Then I reference this context in every URL template tag:

```html
href="{% url 'tracker:ticket_list' team_pk=current_team_pk %}"
```

This results in the desired behavior, but it's a lot of repetition. So, is there a better way?

**Edit:**

Based on Willem Van Onsem's suggestion, I changed the URL template tag to `href="{% url 'tracker:ticket_list' team_pk=team_pk %}"`, referencing the URL kwarg directly. But this doesn't seem to be working reliably. On the index page `/<team_pk>/` loads just fine, and it includes two relevant URLs: `/<team_pk>/` and `/<team_pk>/tickets/`. When I navigate to `/<team_pk>/tickets/`, however, I get another NoReverseMatch error:

```py
NoReverseMatch at /1/tickets/
Reverse for 'home' with keyword arguments '{'team_pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<team_pk>[^/]+)/$']
```

It seems the URL kwarg `<team_pk>` is not being passed for some reason. But the only link to `'home'` is part of my `base.html`, which the other templates are extending. So the relevant template tags are the same.

**Edit 2:**

The view in question:

```py
class TicketTable(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
    table_class = my_tables.TicketTable
    template_name = 'tracker/ticket_list.html'
    filterset_class = TicketFilter
    context_object_name = 'page'
    table_pagination = {"per_page": 10}
    PAGE_TITLE = 'Open Tickets'
    TICKET_STATUS_TOGGLE = 'Show Closed Tickets'
    TICKET_STATUS_TOGGLE_URL = 'tracker:closed_ticket_list'
    DISPLAY_DEV_FILTER = True
    DISPLAY_STATUS_FILTER = True

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['page_title'] = self.PAGE_TITLE
        context['ticket_status_toggle'] = self.TICKET_STATUS_TOGGLE
        context['ticket_status_toggle_url'] = self.TICKET_STATUS_TOGGLE_URL
        context['display_dev_filter'] = self.DISPLAY_DEV_FILTER
        context['display_status_filter'] = self.DISPLAY_STATUS_FILTER
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Ticket.objects.filter_for_team(self.kwargs['team_pk']).filter_for_user(self.request.user).exclude(status='closed')
```

**Edit 3:**

I found a solution to access the URL kwargs without modifying context data. I'm not sure why `team_pk=team_pk` didn't work in the URL tag, but `team_pk=view.kwargs.team_pk` does work.

Comment: **No**, but you do not have to extend the `get_context_data`, since the named URL parameters are also passed to the template directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments and responses from Willem Van Onsem, a friend of mine, and some of my own digging, I found what I think is the DRYest way to do what I was trying to do. I created a custom mixin:

```py
class CommonTemplateContextMixin:
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.kwargs.get('team_pk'):
            context.setdefault('team_pk', self.kwargs.get('team_pk'))
        else:
            context.setdefault('team_pk', self.request.user.teams.all()[0].pk)
        return context
```

Then I subclass this mixin with all my views. Then I have a `team_pk` template tag inside all my templates, and I just add `team_pk=team_pk` to all my URL template tags. The only advantage to using this instead of `team_pk=view.kwargs.team_pk` is that I can add some additional logic for the case when the URL kwarg isn't available.